# Unable to update the page limit in pagination - React JS?

Tags: reactjs

I am using pagination component from following link, in that I am unable to update pageLimit value based on user selection how many rows will display.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-custom-pagination-with-react

https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-river-xneqb

Initially the page limit will be 10. Once the user clicks the button the page limit will be changed to 15. But the paginations page limit is not changing even after updating the component also.

```
   " import Pagination from "./components/Pagination";

    class App extends Component {
      state = {
        pageLimit : 10
      };

      handlePageLimit = () => {
        this.setState({pageLimit : 15})
        console.log("pagelimit inside fun",this.state.pageLimit)
      }

        return (     
                <div className="d-flex flex-row py-4 align-items-center">
                  <Pagination
                    totalRecords={this.state.totalCountries}
                    pageLimit={this.state.pageLimit}
                    pageNeighbours={1}
                    onPageChanged={this.onPageChanged}
                  />

            <button onClick={this.handlePageLimit}>Click</button>

            </div>
        );"
```

Please help me to resolve such that when the button clicks the page limit should be changed to 15.

Comment: so when you click the button, it calls `handlePageLimit`? is it actually being called and it logs out `console.log("pagelimit inside fun",this.state.pageLimit)`? if the issue is that your console output is wrong, the problem there is that state isn't synchronous like that so you can't call `setState` and then on the next expect to be able immediately reference the new state. you'd have to put the console.log in a `componentDidUpdate` or inside `render` for it log out fresh state. if the `Pagination` component isn't updating

Comment: after looking at the codesandbox you posted, the problem is in that `Pagination` component that you're given - it assigns a `pageLimit` in the constructor but never looks at the props changing to reassign what its `this.pageLimit` is. so, the simplest way to fix this, without changing the `Pagination` component, would be to give it a key prop like `<Pagination key={this.state.pageLimit} ... />` which means the component will be rebuilt from scratch every time the page limit changes though it's not a good answer as we should change the Pagination component but that seems like a stretch for this

Answer (score 1):

This guide has so many issues it would be better to just find another ready solution and implement it from scratch. If you want to keep using that you should start here:

Building on Tom Finney's comment, you would need to use componentDidUpdate and then work from there manually updating stuff in your render function:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.pageLimit !== this.props.pageLimit) {
      this.pageLimit = this.props.pageLimit;
      this.totalPages = Math.ceil(this.totalRecords / this.pageLimit);
      this.gotoPage(1); // If you want to reset to first page on limit change
    }
  }
```

Totally not worth the effort.

Comment: Hi @plamenh, can you please help me for "Update currentPage value"

Comment: While moving next page then it's working properly, but when I'm selecting no.of rows that time currentPage should be "1" ,but it activates the previous currentPage..How to fix that

Comment: You just need to add this line in the componentDidUpdate function: `this.gotoPage(1);`

Comment: I tried that but it's not working. could you give some other suggestion